# MySQL Update set Value only if flag = 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Query:

```
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`,`image`)
   VALUES(112,'asdf.jpg'),(113,'foobar.png')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `id`VALUES(`id`),
  `image` = IF(image_uploaded = 0, VALUES(`image`),image);
```

The worse: its properly working but not as i want.

What i want: The images should only be updated if the field "image_uploaded" is set to 0.

Any ideas?

The Background: I have a DB-Table with data. Now each night a cronjob calls an API-Fn to get new Data from another DB and write it down to my table. This function is getting all items from the second DB so its currently just overwriting my existing data. Now my Application allows changes on data i got from the 2nd DB and overwrites the changes in my own Table. So the Problem is: I need the ability to edit Data via my App AND update Data via API without colliding. The User may change the "image" but all other things should be updated from the 2nd DB. The Image should only be overwritten if it wasn't uploaded manually.

Comment: i only want this field to be updated if the image_uploaded is 0 but all other fields to be updated anyways

Answer (score 2):

Without playing around with `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` I'm not sure, if it can handle this situation. I'd work around it by using another (temporary) table.

It's the same structure as your target_table plus a column (in the example `sid`) to indicate if the entry exists in your target_table or not.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_whatever (
sid int,
id int, image varchar(50)
);
```

Now we insert the data you want to insert into your target_table into the newly created table first and check with coalesce() and left joining, if the entry already exists. I'm assuming here, that id is your primary key.

```
INSERT INTO tmp_whatever (sid, id, image)
SELECT 
COALESCE(t.id, 0),
id, image 
FROM (
  SELECT 112 AS id,'asdf.jpg' AS image
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 113,'foobar.png'
) your_values v
LEFT JOIN your_target_table t ON v.id = t.id;
```

Then we update the target_table...

```
UPDATE your_target_table t INNER JOIN tmp_whatever w ON t.id = w.id AND w.sid <> 0 
SET t.image = w.image
WHERE t.image_uploaded = 0;
```

And finally we insert the rows not already existing...

```
INSERT INTO your_target_table (id, image)
SELECT
id, image 
FROM tmp_whatever
WHERE sid = 0;
```

While I was writing this down, it came to my mind, that I might have had wrong assumptions on what your problem is. This

> The worse: its properly working but not as i want.

is definitely not the way to ask a question or describe a problem. I answered because I have a good day :)  (and it's the reason why you get downvotes, btw)
Anyway, another cause of "not as i want" could be, that you're missing a unique index in your table. Though a primary key is a unique key, afaik/iirc `ON DUPLICATE KEY` relies on a unique index on another column to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and honesty. To describe my Problem a bit better i updated the Question. The reason i want to get this working in one single query is the huge amount of data behind this problem.

Comment: You only added "what I want:" to your question, that's not what I call "describing a problem better", no offense ;) Well, I gave you my 2 cents, and the two upvotes I got so far tell me, that I'm not that wrong with it. Your statement doesn't look so wrong to me, I would've tried it the same way. But since it doesn't seem to work...